# Aligning images in a single line in wordpress divi theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a screenshot below which I **have to replicate in Wordpress**. I am using Wordpress Divi theme.

**1st Image:**

[image]

**2nd Image:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering which **option I should select in the New Module section of wordpress (2nd Image)** so that I am successfully able to align images in a single line **(1st image)**.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you have to choose the *Image* module to insert an image. Insert each image in a separate Image module.
But before that, make sure you have inserted a row and all of these modules are inserted into that particular row.

Answer (score 0):

Two primary options come to mind:

1. You can create a single image as a composite of the 7 images (logos) you show in your first example image. A potential disadvantage of this is the sizing and spacing will be fixed. Although, that could also be to your advantage, since the whole composite image can resize somewhat responsively, it might work just fine.
2. If you want to have 2 or more images in a Column stacked horizontally (as opposed to the default vertical stacking), you can add the following Custom CSS to the page (go to Page settings in Divi Builder; then the `Advanced` tab, then `Custom CSS`) on the Row into which you've put the images (seven of them, in your example).

```
.imageStack .et_pb_image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Shown here:

[image]

On the Row in which you want the images to stack horizontally, go to `Advanced` tab, then the `CSS ID / Classes`, and put in the class `imageStack`.

Shown here:

[image]

As for your second image ... it sounds like you didn't know you need to use the `Image` module. In your case, with method #2 above, you'll be using 7 image modules. The trick is then getting them to not stack vertically. Using method #2 above will achieve that.